# Phonegap iOS iScroll 5 View Moves Up on Virtual Keyboard

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, iscroll

I am using Phonegap, jQuery and iScroll 5 to build a native app for iOS. The iScroll works perfectly except for when I focus on an input field in the footer. The virtual keyboard appears and pushes the entire view up. The header is out of view and I am unable to scroll to the top of the page. When the input field loses focus or blurs, everything goes back to normal. I have read that iScroll does not detect the screen size change, but I am not sure how to fix it. I have tried window.scrollTo(0, 0) and scrollTop() with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggeling with that for weeks.

try

```
body{
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    min-height: 480px; /* Window height for iPhone 5*/
 }
```

in the xml:

```
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
```

and I changed the CDVViewController.m

from

```
CGFloat actualKeyboardHeight = (keyboardFrame.size.height - accessoryHeight);
newFrame.size.height -= actualKeyboardHeight;
```

to

```
newFrame.size.height -= 0;
```

now this works for me, as long as i don't have several input fields on one page, and I actually need some scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The scroller wrapper's scrollTop value maybe changed when the virtualkeyboard is appeared even it's css overflow property is 'hidden';
I reset the wrapper's scrollTop to 0 in the hidekeyboard event handler;